# Can someone try to understand my feedback with my java code?

Tags: java

my Java code isn't quite completed as it should be and this is the feedback that I received but I don't understand it, what do I need to do?

In using the printf statement, you need to explicitly include the 
 printing of a new line at the end of the text that is printed.

As you do not do this the next line you output which contains a # 
 character will be excluded from the comparison.

```
class Main { 
    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");
        int studentNumber = BIO.getInt();

        while(studentNumber > 0) {
            System.out.print("#Please enter the coursework mark : ");
            int courseWork = BIO.getInt();

            System.out.print("#Please enter the exam mark : ");
            int examMark = BIO.getInt();

            double average = (double)(courseWork + examMark) / 2;
            System.out.printf("sn = " + studentNumber
                + " ex = " + examMark + " cw = " + courseWork 
                + " mark = " + average);



            System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");
            studentNumber = BIO.getInt();
        } 

        System.out.print("#End of data");


    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you missed the info about `BIO`. What kind of class it is? Import is missing for it.

Comment: Have you run your code? Can you post the output?

Comment: It's just something my university uses that is saved inside ext in Java.

Comment: #Please enter the student number : 11123456
#Please enter the coursework mark : 72
#Please enter the exam mark : 71
sn = 11123456 ex = 71 cw = 72 mark = 71.5#Please enter the student number : 1102346
#Please enter the coursework mark : 79
#Please enter the exam mark : 40
sn = 1102346 ex = 40 cw = 79 mark = 59.5#Please enter the student number : 0
#End of data

Comment: Cool, so add a "\n" at the end of your printf() line....ie "System.out.printf("sn = " + studentNumber
                + " ex = " + examMark + " cw = " + courseWork 
                + " mark = " + average + "\n");

Answer (score 2):

Michael Zucchetta answer is almost complete. you might want tot do:

```
System.out.print("\n#Please enter the student number : \n");
```

because you want to go down a line after you give the results at the end of the loop.

plus you might wanna do

```
System.out.print("\n#End of data");
```

for the same reason

finally you might want to learn about `System.out.println`

Comment: One could also make use of `System.out.println("My Text")` which appends a system specific line break at the end

Answer (score 0):

That at the end of

```
System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : ");
```

you have to put a '\n' that makes a newline:

```
System.out.print("#Please enter the student number : \n");
```

Or you can use the System.out.println which already does it on its own